# Using asp:Literal text in html attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-literal

quick question.  Is there a way to use asp:Literal text in an HTML attribute?

Example

```
<asp:Literal Text="hidden" runat="server" ID="ClassTag"></asp:Literal>

<tr class='<%= ClassTag %>' run="server" > </tr>
```

I am working on an overall solution to a repeater table row collapsing problem ([asp:repeater collapsing table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707543/asprepeater-collapsing-table-rows/44711490#44711490)) for context, and this is perhaps the last thing I'm stuck on.

Please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: If the tr was not running on the server side, yes, you could.

Comment: Why is the `tr` running on the server anyway?  It has no `ID` so it is unaddressable (except by walking control collections, but... ewww).  Remove that and what you have should work fine if you also add the `.Text` property to `ClassTag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but are you just trying to set the class on the TR from code?

In that case, write the following the ASP.NET:

```
<tr runat="server" ID="CustomRow">
```

And in the codebehind set the class through the Attributes collection:

```
CustomRow.Attributes.Add("class", "[desired css class]");
```

Comment: I actually ended up with a solution very close to this one.  Thank you!